# Css orientation iphone

Tags: css

Need a code which will change the properties of the divs, depending on the location of the device iphone.
Before this code to work now stopped doing that?

```
@media all and (orientation:portrait) { 
  .portarait {display:block;}
  .landscpace {display:none;}
}

@media all and (orientation:landscape) { 
  .portarait {display:none;}
  .landscpace {display:block;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have misspelled .portarait and .landscpace instead of .portrait and .landscape?

This code should work otherwise, but the actual class names are unclear from your question.